How to compare sales from the selected period with the same period from the previous month in Superset?
I'm creating a dashboard in Superset and I need to compare sales in "big number" graphs based on the dates selected in a dashboard date filter. I added filters for products, state, and more, and a date range filter so users can choose the date range they want. I need to create two "big number" charts that display:

The total sales for the period selected by the user in the date filter.

The total sales for the same period in the previous month.


Example:  If the user selects the date range '2024-08-01' to '2024-08-15', I want to display:


The total sales for the period '2024-08-01' to '2024-08-15' and 



The total sales for the period '2024-07-01' to '2024-07-15'. 



I don't know how I can make a graph that takes the dates entered in the dashboard's date filter, and brings in sales from the previous period.  I tried to create this rule, through the SQL Custom of the graph, in the filter part. This way:
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('{{ from_dttm }}'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)ANDDATE_SUB('{{ to_dttm }}'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

It doesn't return any value.
Is the syntax I'm using for the date filters correct? Are {{ from_dttm }} and {{ to_dttm }} the correct parameters to use in custom SQL queries in Superset?  How can I adjust my query to correctly compare the selected period to the same period in the previous month using the dashboard date filters?

Some higher level graphs such as the line chart does have a advanced analytics version which can be used to compare your values to N minus X times in the same graph which could solve your issue more easily
If you want specifically big number chart, i would advise to do another virtual datasets which would create a dynamic virtual dataset with value equivalent to N - 1 months
Here is my boiler plate for jinja datetime handling, do not forget to handle case where date value aren't entered or it can become ugly
AND
{% if from_dttm %} date_value > "{{ from_dttm }}"
AND {% endif %} 
{% if to_dttm %} date_value < "{{ to_dttm }}"
AND {% endif %} true


Yes, the line graph does what I need well. But I have a request to do the same for big number. I made the following query SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE {% if from_dttm %} date_value > DATE_SUB(DATE("{{ from_dttm }}"), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND {% endif %} {% if to_dttm %} date_value < DATE_SUB(DATE("{{ to_dttm }}"), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND {% endif %} true When I place the big number on the graph and choose a period from the dashboard filter, it returns this error: "No data after filtering or data is null for the latest time record".
